# Why the form does not appear when calling from .dll in c#

Tags: c#

this namespace in .dll file  
this .dll to check if some file exsits  
and If file exists.Check the content of the file

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckData
{



public class CheckFileContent : Form
{
    public  void Check(Form  CreateFile)
    {

        try
        {

            // check file if exsits
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "ConReq.HP"))
            {
               CreateFile = new Form();
               CreateFile.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                //If file exists.Check the content of the file

                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "ConReq.HP");
```

check if first line contents specific word (DBname=)

```
                if (lines[0].Substring(0, 7) != "DBname=")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
```

check if first line didn't contents specific word (DBname=)

```
                else if (lines[0].Substring(7, lines[0].Length - 7) == "")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
```

check if first line contents specific word (server=)

```
                else if (lines[1].Substring(0, 7) != "Server=")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
```

check if first line didn't contents specific word (server=)

```
                else if (lines[1].Substring(7, lines[1].Length - 7) == "")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
```

check if first line contents specific word (Data Source=)

```
                else if (lines[2].Substring(0, 12) != "Data Source=")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
```

check if first line didn't contents specific word (Data Source=)

```
                else if (lines[2].Substring(12, lines[2].Length - 12) == "")
                {
                    CreateFile = new Form();
                    CreateFile.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception check_e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(check_e.Message, check_e.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

when called .dll in main form
and called method to check if file exsits

```
CheckFileContent cheek = new CheckFileContent();
        cheek.Check(CheckFileCon.ActiveForm);
```

this form called to create new file when file not exsits
[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNcQE.jpg)

but
[That's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A15Ek.jpg)

Comment: Hi Geanny and welcome to StackOverflow.  The reason you're seeing that window is that your code merely creates a Form object and shows it, and that's what an Form object looks like when it's displayed.  To get what you want you should create a new form, derived from Form, and show that instead.

Comment: I see that the CheckFileContent class is derived from Form.  Is this where you've defined the form you want to see?

Comment: @Ian thank you i get what i want